# Rearrange a JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JSON like this:

```
"hotel": [
{
    "id": 90091,
    "hotelGroup": "A1",
    "hotelRoom": [
    {
        "name":"Room1",
        "minimumQuantity": 1,
        "maximumQuantity": 6,
    },
    {
        "name":"Room2",
        "minimumQuantity": 7,
        "maximumQuantity": 12,
    }
]},
{
    "id": 90089,
    "hotelGroup": "A4",
    "hotelRoom": [
    {
        "name":"Room1",
        "minimumQuantity": 0,
        "maximumQuantity": 0,
    }]
}]
```

And I try to rearrange the JSON to below format:

```
hotel = [{
    name: "Room1",
    RoomInfo: [{
        hotelGroup: "A1",
        Stops: [
            {"minimumQuantity": 1,"maximumQuantity": 6}
        ]}, 
        {
            hotelGroup: "A4",
            Stops: [
                {"minimumQuantity": 0,"maximumQuantity": 0}
            ]
        }
   ]}, 
   {
       name: "Room2",
       RoomInfo: [{
           Name: "A1",
           Stops: [
               {"minimumQuantity": 7,"maximumQuantity": 12}
           ]
      }]
 }]
```

Is there someone who could help ?
I want to group by name of the hotel. And each of the hotels name has its own hotel group and its stop.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Hi, I had try to rearrange the structure, but I able rearrange into until RoomInfo. But fail to made a list of Stops in RoomInfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously converted your JSON to just a regular array but you get the idea.

```js
const hotel = [{
    "id": 90091,
    "hotelGroup": "A1",
    "hotelRoom": [{
        "name": "Room1",
        "minimumQuantity": 1,
        "maximumQuantity": 6,
      },
      {
        "name": "Room2",
        "minimumQuantity": 7,
        "maximumQuantity": 12,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 90089,
    "hotelGroup": "A4",
    "hotelRoom": [{
      "name": "Room1",
      "minimumQuantity": 0,
      "maximumQuantity": 0,
    }]
  }
];

const newHotels = hotel.map(obj => {
  const { hotelGroup, hotelRoom } = obj;
  const newObj = {};

  newObj['name'] = hotelRoom[0]['name'];

  newObj['RoomInfo'] = hotelRoom.map(({ minimumQuantity, maximumQuantity }) => {
    return {
      hotelGroup,
      Stops: [{
        minimumQuantity,
        maximumQuantity
      }]
    };
  });
  
  return newObj;
});

console.log(newHotels);
```

Comment: Hi, Thank for your help.

Comment: I thought it is difficult to do.

Comment: I have try to rearrange the JSON to 1 level of JSON(not nested).

Comment: var tmp = {}
$scope.data.forEach(function (newHotels) {
     var tempKey = newHotels.name;

    if (!tmp.hasOwnProperty(tempKey)) {
          tmp[tempKey] = {
                  "name": item.name,
                  "RoomInfo": []
                };
       }
     tmp[tempKey].RoomInfo.push(newHotels);

    });
    $scope.results = Object.keys(tmp).map(function (key) {
     return tmp[key];
  });

Comment: I'd make this into a new question.